# curious on `instanceof` in Groovy/Java

Tags: java, groovy, instanceof

I've encounter the `instanceof` issue in Groovy, and find the `Class` cannot be defined by variable, but `isCase` or `isAssignableFrom` works as expected.

Here are details :

```
// works
assert '' instanceof java.lang.String

// not working
Class clz = ''.getClass()
assert '' instanceof clz                 // ERROR: unable to resolve class clz
assert '' in clz                         // works

// debug info:
println clz                              // class java.lang.String
println clz.getClass()                   // class java.lang.Class
```

`isCase()` and `isAssignableFrom()` works, I assume because of those two are **function**

```
Class clz = ''.getClass()

// works
assert clz.isCase( '' )
assert clz.isCase( [] ) == false

// works
assert clz.isAssignableFrom( ''.getClass() )
assert clz.isAssignableFrom( [:].getClass() ) == false
```

But why `instanceof` cannot be using class-type variable ? by the way, groovy version is `Groovy Version: 4.0.18 JVM: 21.0.2 Vendor: Homebrew OS: Mac OS X`

Comment: that's coming from java

Comment: okay... title updated.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2

probably the best explanation is here ^^^

`instanceof` operator works at compile-time and at run-time. to make checks at compile time it requires exact class name.

more, since jdk 16 there is a new syntax (https://openjdk.org/jeps/394)

instead of

```
if (obj instanceof String) {
    String s = (String) obj;
    ...
}
```

you can use

```
if (obj instanceof String s) {
    ...
}
```

with this syntax it's obvious that you need exact type and not a class reference

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just want to know if "`instanceof` operator works at **compile-time** and at **run-time**",  how `isInstance()` and `isAssignableFrom()` works ?

Answer (score 1):

> But why `instanceof` cannot be using class-type variable ?

If you are asking "why did they design `instanceof` with this restriction" ... the decisions were taken ~30 years ago, and (AFAIK) there is no extant publicly visible rationale for the design.

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77991743/139985) the Java 16+ `instanceof` syntax extension relies on the type being known at compile time.  So don't expect the restriction to be lifted.

If you need to do the equivalent of `instanceof` using a `Class` reference, you can use reflection to do it; see the `Class` API and the `isInstance(Object)` and `T cast(Object)` methods.

```
if (clz.isInstance(obj)) {
   ...
}
```

But once you have established that `obj` is an instance of some (dynamic) class, you stuck with the problem of how to *use* the instance.  This can only be done reflectively.  And if you think about it, that is *another* reason why supporting `instanceof` with `Class` references wouldn't be much help.

Comment: thanks for your answer. my situation is not "`obj` is an instance of dynamic class". It's to identify Jenkins Credential Type. So Credential ID is a `String`, but different credential type is defined by different Class. So the purpose is, String ( already know ) -> which Class -> which DSL should be use ( [sample code](https://gist.github.com/marslo/1be12ef31c7bc5b0501c2cfe112c3b9e) ). And yes, `isInstance()` works well